# Java websocket client throws exception at send method (TooTallNate)

Tags: java, sockets, websocket

I got a Java project that is supposed to create a websocket client using TooTallNate. Everything seems to be working, connection is succesful to the websocket server but when I call the send method on the socket I get the following:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-1" org.java_websocket.exceptions.WebsocketNotConnectedException
    at org.java_websocket.WebSocketImpl.send(WebSocketImpl.java:608)
    at org.java_websocket.WebSocketImpl.send(WebSocketImpl.java:585)
    at org.java_websocket.client.WebSocketClient.send(WebSocketClient.java:207)
    at Main$2.run(Main.java:39)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
opened connection
```

Connection is successfully opened but the send method throws the exception.

I got the following code:

```
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue;

import org.java_websocket.client.WebSocketClient;
import org.java_websocket.handshake.ServerHandshake;

public class Main
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
    {
        Queue<String> queue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<String>();

        Runnable producer = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
                    queue.offer(String.valueOf(i));
                }
            }
        };

        Thread producerThread = new Thread(producer);
        producerThread.start();

        Runnable consumer = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                wsClient c = null;
                try {
                    c = new wsClient( new URI( "ws://echo.websocket.org") );
                } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                c.connect();
                c.send("hello");

                while(true) {
                    String value = queue.poll();
                    if(value.equals("100")){
                        return;
                    }
                    System.out.println(value);
                }
            }
        };

        Thread consumerThread = new Thread(consumer);
        consumerThread.start();

        producerThread.join();
        consumerThread.join();

    }
}
```

Which simply creates a queue, adds data to it and then polls data from it while at the same time creating a websocket connection to a websocket server but as soon as I try to send data via the socket it throws the exception. Does someone know what could be the issue?

Comment: what is inside `org.java_websocket.client.WebSocketClient`?

Comment: @NikolayShevchenko https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket/blob/master/src/main/java/org/java_websocket/client/WebSocketClient.java and wsClient: https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket/blob/master/src/main/example/ExampleClient.java

Comment: @MA Were you able to solve this? I'm facing the same issue...

Answer (score 0):

Here you have used `connect()` method, This is a non blocking method, which is starting the connection/handshake etc.

If you wanna send a frame right after connecting, please use the method `connectBlocking()` instead of `connect()`.

`connectBlocking()` method blocks the thread till the connection is established

All credits go to https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket/issues/642